# Format decimal without trailing zeros

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to format `Decimal`s without trailing zeros. [`Decimal.normalize()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html#decimal.Decimal.normalize) gets me most of the way there, but any value that's a multiple of 10 is converted to engineering notation. E.g.,

```
>>> import decimal
>>> for number in map(decimal.Decimal, ['0.00', '0.25', '0.50', '1.00', '5.00', '10.00', '15.00', '20.00']):
...     print(number.normalize())
0
0.25
0.5
1
5
1E+1 # Should be `10`.
15
2E+1 # Should be `20`.
```

Is there some context option to disable engineering notation for `.normalize()`, or a different formatting method that I'm missing?

Comment: I tried your code with Python 2.7.6, I am getting 0.00
0.25
0.50
1.00
5.00
10.00
15.00
20.00

Comment: `"%g"` will trim trailing zeros ...

Comment: Check out the `remove_exponent` recipe in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html#decimal.Decimal.normalize)